# Is is possible to skip the middle leg of a flight?

Tags: air-travel, short-connections, missed-flights

I am flying Bangalore - Frankfurt - Wroclaw and back, with the following itinerary:

`BLR-FRA-WRO: 5 Feb`
`WRO-FRA: 18 Feb`
`FRA-BLR: 11 Mar`

Looks like I'll miss the `WRO-FRA` flight because of some personal complications.

Am I totally screwed or can I somehow salvage this situation and still make it to the `FRA-BLR`leg?

**My flight leaves in 10 hours and I can't make it to WRO on time**. Is there a way out of the situation?

PS: I'm flying Lufthansa and their customer care is closed till after my flight leaves :(

Comment: Thanks. Fortunately, that's exactly what I did. I called the 24/7 Helpline, which is a German number (I used Skype to call them). The option for English was provided, and the operator modified my ticket for 1.5 Euros and said I could just embark on the FRA-BLR journey on the 11th of March. Problem solved!

Comment: I certainly do. They made it super easy. I don't have a lot of air miles or any elite club membership with Lufthansa. Which makes their customer service even better. Super stuff

Comment: @nikjohn: Out of curiosity, did you have to tell them why you're skipping it? Did they seem to look for a valid reason (e.g. personal issues outside of your control) or did they not care?

Comment: Nope, but that could've been just my operator

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You *need* to speak to Lufthansa, and their international customer services line is open 24/7 - +49 69 86 799 799

https://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/in/help_contact/contactsworldwide?l=en&cid=1000267

Even though it says "in German", you shouldn't have issues with English.

Comment: Thanks. Fortunately, that's exactly what I did. I called the 24/7 Helpline, which is a German number (I used Skype to call them). The option for English was provided, and the operator modified my ticket for 1.5 Euros and said I could just embark on the FRA-BLR journey on the 11th of March. Problem solved!

Comment: What's the problem? I don't think it would have occurred to me to check either online or by calling - I would just have taken the flight I wanted and not the one I couldn't. Why the 'need' (and with emphasis) - and why did it cost OP (albeit a tiny sum) to... what, not take a paid-for flight that the operator can now resell?

Comment: @OliverFord most airlines have conditions that your itinerary must be traveled in the correct order, or subsequent parts may be cancelled - its a similar issue to hidden city ticketing and return flights, or buying a return ticket just to fly the return leg.  That is why he has to speak to the airline, lest they cancel the last leg.  For the airline its about revenue protection, as particular flights on an itinerary may be more expensive if not bought as part of the package.  No guarantees that this is the case here, but in these situations you must talk to the airline to be in the safe side.

Comment: @Moo Wow, thanks for elaborating. Like I said, if it were me, I definitely would have fallen foul of that.