# Skipping the final leg of the flight on Turkish Airlines - how to get luggage out?

Tags: luggage, turkish-airlines, connecting-flights

I am not much experienced in flight rules (usually I just buy the ticket and get the flight).

In about 1 week, I will be travelling from Incheon in Korea to Tirana in Albania on Turkish Airlines. This is a round-trip fully-flexible ticket.

I have a transit in Istanbul of less than 2 hours. However, I want to  instead stay for some time in Istanbul and travel a bit in the Middle East.

What should I do if I want to get my luggage in Istanbul and not board the 2nd flight from Istanbul to Tirana? (I don't need a visa to enter Turkey.)

I do not want to push the 2nd flight, because I have no idea when I might want to go back. Also, I really don't want my baggage flying to Albania or getting lost.

Comment: Did you try telling the airline you only want to go to Istanbul and asking them what it will cost to change your ticket accordingly.

Comment: Similar question - http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88290/is-is-possible-to-skip-the-middle-leg-of-a-flight/88291#88291

Comment: the problem is that this is the return flight.

Answer (score 6):

Update: the asker has clarified in comments that the flight they wish to skip is the final leg of the *return* journey, which alters the situation somewhat as there would be no subsequent trips under risk of cancellation.

However, my advice still stands - you need to talk to the airline, there is no other way to get the luggage off loaded at the interstitial airport, only the airline can change the final destination of the luggage.

One trick is, when checking the luggage in Korea, to ask for the luggage to be made available at the Turkey stop for ***"medical reasons"***, and if they ask why you cannot take said "medical reasons" in hand luggage (they should not, thats confidential medical information they are asking for), just respond that you will be carrying "sharps" and they need to be checked into the hold.  I see no reason why the airline wouldn't provide the baggage on request.

I do not know the layout of Istanbul airport, so I am unsure if the airline may ask difficult questions such as "how do you intend to recheck the luggage items", especially if you need a Turkish visa to enter Turkey and 
you may need to do that to recheck the luggage, I am not sure.

Old answer: You *need* to speak to the airline, because there is a very high chance that if you do not complete all legs of the outward bound journey (Incheon to Tirana) then the airline may cancel your return flight completely.

Speak to the airline and change the ticket to a multi-city ticket, where the outbound trip terminates in Turkey and the return trip flies from wherever you want to return to Korean from.

Related - [Is is possible to skip the middle leg of a flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88290/is-is-possible-to-skip-the-middle-leg-of-a-flight/88291#88291)

Comment: problem is that this is the return flight

Comment: and i actually want to lose the 2nd leg of my flight.

Comment: i just want my luggage to be with me in istanbul not fly to tirana, and also i dont want to take any fine form the company. even though seems absurd being fined for not taking a flight about which i have already paid